# apply a bit mask in python

Tags: python, binary, bitmask

I would like to apply a bit mask to a variable in python to figure out which bits are set. I've been trying around but haven't figured out the correct way to do it. My variable is binary and to display its value, i use th function hexlify():

```
    corr = fh.read(1)
    mac = fh.read(6)[-3:]
    print "corr "+ hexlify(corr)
```

no I have troubles to apply the bitmask to corr:

```
    print hexlify(corr&0x01)
```

it says

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

but why is that? Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Obviously you cannot use binary OR on a `str` and an `int`.  You have to convert corr to an `int` before, but you have not shown any relevant info... What is corr? What is hexlify?

Comment: hexifly just converts it to a string i think (like  `"%x"%my_int`)

Comment: Might be worth looking at https://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/ or http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BitVector/3.1.1 which may make life easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I don't like this but it seems to work:

```
print (int(hexlify(corr),16))&0x01
```

this converts corr to a hex string which again gets converted baclk to an integer, base 16 before the mask gets applied..... any hints on how I could solve this otherwise would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: This is by far very complicated: you take your byte, hexlify it, turn it back to a numeric value and then apply the `&`...

Answer (score 1):

because corr is a string and it expects an int

```
print hexlify(int(corr)&0x01) # if corr is like "12352"
print hexlify(ord(corr)&0x01) #if corr is like "\x##"

>>> ord("\x10")
16
>>> ord("\x10")&0x01
0
```

Comment: but I need to hexlify it to display it first which would indicate it being a binary number, no? :o

Comment: And when i int() it, I get this: print hexlify(int(corr)&0x01)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x01'

Comment: and if I unhexlify() it, I get this:  print hexlify(unhexlify(corr)&0x01)
TypeError: Odd-length string

Comment: with ord: print hexlify(ord(corr)&0x01)
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not int

Comment: what dpes it print if you print corr right before you want to hexifly it ?

Comment: If I do not hexlify it, it doesn't print anything cause it's got a binary value of 0x01 (in this case) thus i need to hexlify it to see anything

Comment: `print repr(corr),type(corr)  `   do that RIGHT before you try to call hexlify on it anded with 0x01

Answer (score 0):

As `corr` comes from

```
corr = fh.read(1)
```

I suppose you want to read one byte and then continue with the value of this byte.

Then you should work with `ord()` and `chr()`:

```
if corr: # it could as well be empty!
    print "corr "+ hexlify(chr(ord(corr) & 0x01))
```

`ord()` gets you the byte value of this byte, which you can process and then, as `hexlify()` seems to expect a string, re-covert it to a single-byte string.